# How to bind a gridview with two different lists?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two lists of different types

```
List<Report>
List<Newsletter>
```

Is there a way to bind a gridview with both lists? Both classes are not implemented from a common interface.

I just need to display the `name` and `status` within the object properties. I mean, the type of the properties i want to bind is common to both list.

Comment: you mean the name of the properties..

Comment: You asked yesterday about how to make them into 1 list. You can bind a readonly gridview to that list.

Comment: No, Name is a property within my object. It's of type string and Status is an enum

Comment: @Henk, i'm having different type of requirements. Yesterday, i just need to get the data as a plain text format. Now that i have to bind it to a grid.

Comment: And do you want to edit the data? How/where do you want to save the changes?

Comment: I dont want to edit the data from within the grid

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**CS**

```
gv.DataSource=reportList
              .Select(x =>  new {x.Status,Name= x.text })
              .Concat(
              newsList
              .Select(x =>  new {Status=x.Status.ToString(),Name= x.text }) );
gv.DataBind();
```

Comment: I think thats "cleaner" then my version as you can use LINQ with an anonymous type, which does not require to create an additional class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cast() method then union the lists

```
grv.DataSource = l1.Cast<object>().Union(l2.Cast<object>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you could create some kind of intermediate class:

```
public class ReporterNewsletterMixer
{
    public Reporter Reporter { get; set; }
    public Newsletter Newsletter { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            if(Reporter == null)
                return Newsletter.Name;
            return Reporter.Name;
        }
    }
    //same for status

    public ReporterNewsletterMixer(Reporter reporter) { Reporter = reporter; }
    public ReporterNewsletterMixer(Newsletter news) { Newsletter = news; }
}
```

Then you could mix the two lists together:

```
List<ReporterNewsletterMixer> mixed = new List<ReporterNewsletterMixer>();
reporters.Foreach(r => mixed.Add(new ReporterNewsletterMixer(r));
newsletter.Foreach(n => mixed.Add(new ReporterNewsletterMixer(n));
//bind to mixed
```

Answer (score 0):

In such scenario I would use Linq-To-Objects to join between two collections and select only the properties I want to bind to GridView (resulting in anonymous collection).
Then this anonymous collection can be used as data source of the GridView.

You can see great example on how L2O join can be done [in this link](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx)

How to bind resulting data to GridView - you can see example [in this article](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-bind-gridview-using-linq-join.html)